# Método TO_DATE em Oracle SQL tá gerando um Timestamp não intencional, como removê-lo?

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho uma coluna chamada 'periodo_filtro' em que consta data do tipo (data1 A data2), exemplo: (01/1/2000 A 19/1/2020). Com o código a seguir eu estou removendo a primeira data dessa coluna e criando uma nova tabela com ela:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MINHA_TABELA_NOVA AS (SELECT
     TO_DATE(TRIM(SUBSTR(periodo_filtro, 1,
    INSTR(periodo_filtro, ' ', 1, 1))), 'dd/mm/yyyy') periodo_inicial
FROM
    MINHA_TABELA);
```

pórem o resultado é o seguinte:

[image: resultado]

Como eu faço para que esse timestamp (12:00:00) seja removido dessa coluna? Quero manter apenas a informação de data

Comment: faça a conversão para char novamente e deixe no formato que precisa, por exemplo
`SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('13/07/2021','DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YYYY') DATA FROM DUAL`

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, mas acabei de perceber que eu precisaria esse dado no tipo date, para manipulações futuras. Existe uma outra alternativa?

Comment: o tipo date acompanha a hora, mesmo q seja um "00:00:00", sugiro manter assim e mudar para o formato que quiser na hora de mostrar o valor

Comment: compreendo! vou seguir dessa forma. obrigado pelas respostas